# Is reading sex stories allowed?

Tags: sex

I want to ask that is reading sex stories haram in Islam ? And i am taking guarantee that after reading stories, i will not commit any sin.

Please tell me in Yes or no Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assalam o Allaikum.

Reading that kind of material is a direct Zina of the eyes.

**> Narrated by Muslim, 2657:

> Verily Allah has fixed the very portion of adultery which a man will
> indulge in, and which he of necessity must commit. The adultery of the
> eye is the lustful look, and the adultery of the tongue is the
> licentious speech, the heart desires and yearns, which the parts may
> or may not put into effect**

.

**> Quran Al-Isra (17:32)

> And do not approach unlawful sexual intercourse. Indeed, it is ever an
> immorality and is an evil way**

Answer (score -1):

No brother you can't read sexual stories

Comment: For whom scholars such as ibn Hazm have written Tawq al-Hamam then?